# How to query records in Elasticsearch where a property has value?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to search for all records in my Elasticsearch where the field `images` has value? The `images` type is `object`.

I tried the following

```
GET /records/_search
{
  "query": {
    "exists": {
      "field": "images"
    }
  }
}
```

and I also tried the following

```
GET /records/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "images"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But the above two calls returns 0 hits.

However, when I execute the following command, I get a record where `images` have value

```
GET /records/_doc/8875352
```

```
"images" : [
  {
    "path" : "1/8875352/1.jpg",
    "is_preferred" : false,
    "object_id" : 1
  },
  {
    "path" : "1/8875352/2.jpg",
    "is_preferred" : false,
    "object_id" : 2
  },
  {
    "path" : "1/8875352/3.jpg",
    "is_preferred" : false,
    "object_id" : 3
  },
  {
    "path" : "1/8875352/4.jpg",
    "is_preferred" : false,
    "object_id" : 4
  },
  {
    "path" : "1/8875352/5.jpg",
    "is_preferred" : false,
    "object_id" : 5
  },
  {
    "path" : "1/8875352/6.jpg",
    "is_preferred" : false,
    "object_id" : 6
  },
  {
    "path" : "1/8875352/7.jpg",
    "is_preferred" : false,
    "object_id" : 7
  },
  {
    "path" : "1/8875352/8.jpg",
    "is_preferred" : false,
    "object_id" : 8
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that my first query is actually correct

```
GET /records/_search
{
  "query": {
    "exists": {
      "field": "images"
    }
  }
}
```

The problem was that `images` field is not indexed. The indices was created like this

```
PUT /records
{
   "mappings":{
      "properties":{
         "tags":{
            "type":"keyword"
         },
         "summary":{
            "type":"text"
         },
         "@timestamp":{
            "type":"date"
         },
         "images":{
            "type":"object",
            "enabled":false
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Note that `"enabled":false` will disable indexing for that field thus making it not searchable.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all records in where the `images` has at least 1 value, using the below query

```
{
  "query": {
    "exists": {
      "field": "images.path"
    }
  }
}
```

OR you can use a script to filter data

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "source": "doc['images.path.keyword'].length > 0",
            "lang": "painless"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Jay please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: You should also explain why the first is better than the second solution ;-)

Comment: @ESCoder it does not solve the problem. but check out my answer to find out why my first query was failing.

Comment: @Val yes, I will update my answer with that explanation as well :-)

Comment: @Jay may I know why my query didn't solve your problem ?

Comment: @ESCoder because the field is not indexed. Please check my answer for explanation